# Texas hold em raising

Tags: texas-hold-em

I'm quite new to the game and was wondering about raises. I have been told that someone cannot raise their own bet in a betting round, but can the initial better raise his own bet if there are only two players left in the round?

Comment: What would make you think two player left in the round would change cannot raise their own bet?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to explain how the betting and raising works in Texas Hold'em would be to show you. Let's assume we have a table of 6 players. Each player has 1,000 chips, the small blind is 10 and the big blind is 20. We are also playing No limit, meaning the players can bet any amount once it's double the previous bet. A small note would be to be aware, that some tournaments allow a 50% betting rule but lets keep it simple for the moment.

- Player 1 is the dealer.
- Player 2 is the small blind and has to put in 10 chips before seeing any cards.
- Player 3 is the big blind and has to put in 20 chips before seeing any cards.
- Player 4 has the choice of doing several things, they can choose to call, fold or raise. Let's say player 4 raises, they must raise double the previous bet, which is the big blind. So player 4 has to raise to 40 chips, but in no limit they can bet as much as they want.
- Player 5 again has the choice of calling, folding or raising. Player 4 has raised so if player 5 wants to raise they must bet at least double what player 4 has bet.
- Player 6 has the same options as above. The other players 1,2,3 also have the option of calling or raising too once it is their trun to act.

So a few things can happen here. Either someone can call player 4's raise, in which case player 4 will not get another chance to bet, and the flop will be put out on the board.

Let's say player 5 raises to 80 chips after player 4's raise to 40. If this happen and the action gets back to player 4, they now again have all of their options of call, fold or raise. So player 4 can again raise. If they raise again, player 5 can raise again too.

To sum it up, if a player has to put more chips in to call another player's bet they have all of their options of fold, call or raise.

Comment: There's also the situation where Player 4 may raise to 40 chips, and the player 5 Call those 40 chips. But if either of Players 6/1/2/3 decides to raise, Player 4 WILL be able to raise again

Answer (score 1):

Many sources for rules of poker.  This is [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker).

You cannot re-raise when it gets back to you (your own bet) unless your bet was raised.
There are just a couple exceptions:

- if someone went all in and did not cover the min raise then you cannot re-raise
- if the initial forced bet to the BB is just called the BB can still raise when it comes around to them

Comment: `You cannot raise unless you have been raised.` unless someone has bet out in front of you.

Comment: @Michael And that is exactly what I said.  Are you disputing either of the two exceptions in that answer?

Comment: No, but I see you have reworded the sentence I objected to.  While I realize it was correct in the context of the question (which only asked about the case where you had already bet) standing by itself it seemed it might confuse somebody.

Comment: @Michael Whatever.  "Unless someone as bet has bet out in front of you" adds no clarity for me.  If I have been raised then someone bet out in front of me.

Comment: _if someone went all in and did cover the min raise then you cannot re-raise_ - I think you meant to say that if the all-in did _not_ cover the min raise then you cannot re-raise (since their all-in raise was not a proper raise so not re-raisable).

Answer (score 0):

A player can only raise if they have been raised by at least a full minimum raise. If there has only been one bet so far in the betting round, it's pretty easy to tell what a minimum raise is -  it's double the original bet.
It's important to clarify what a minimum raise is when there has already been a raise. It is most definitely **NOT** double the previous bet; it is a raise equal to the previous raise. You have to look at the amount that the bet has been raised *by*, and raise by at least that same amount.

The following action is a very common occurrence in the casino where I am a dealer:
SB: $2
BB: $3
UTG: $6 (a raise of $3)
UTG+1: $10 (a raise of $4 - min raise would be to $9)
Sometimes it's intentional, and sometimes it's just someone who didn't have any $1 chips, and intended to call, but didn't verbalise their action. We used to have $1/$2, and the same thing happened, where the first raise was to $6, and then $10 was exactly a min raise.

This one is also very common, maybe even more common, but it's almost always by accident:
SB: $2
BB: $3
UTG: $3
UTG+1: $11 (a raise of $8)
MP1: $11
MP2: $11
MP3: $19 (a min raise of $8)
There could be any number of callers before the reraise, but it usually gets around to the first player without any $1 chips, who just isn't thinking about how much the min raise would be, and puts in $15 without bothering to verbalise their action, or even to put in $10 followed by another $5, to make it clear that they're only calling. (If they intended to raise, they'd usually make it $20 or $25, or maybe $21 if most of the other players have put $11 in already.) This is where the 50% rule comes in: $15 is too much for a call, but not enough for a raise, so we have to determine whether it is 50% or more of a raise. The min raise is a raise of $8, and the player has put in an extra $4, which is 50% of $8, or to look at it another way, $15 is halfway from $11 to $19, so they are required to put in the rest of the raise.

I realise this is quite a digression, but *"min raise is always double"* is an extremely common misconception, and it's very, very important to dispel it, in order to know exactly when a player is allowed to raise when facing an all-in.

Now consider the following situation on the flop:
A bets $10
B raises to $35
C goes all-in for $65
A calls the additional $55
Is B allowed to raise?
The answer is yes, because the minimum C could raise to was $60 (a raise of $25, because B raised A by $25). B is facing a raise and is allowed to reraise.

However:
A bets $10
B raises to $40
C goes all-in for $65
A calls the additional $55
Is B allowed to raise?
The answer is no, because the minimum raise for C was to $70 (a raise of $30, because B raised A by $30), but C does not have enough to min raise, so without a raise from A, B's $40 has not been raised. B is not facing a raise and so cannot reraise; they can only call or fold.